# Webview and child element of a Expandablelistview

Tags: android

I use a ExpandableListView with parent element and child element, I would throw un'intent of son sends me on webview activities. Of course the webview load where the url should be the same for all figli.Grazie in advance

This is the main activity,

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // INI AGREGADO
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new       com.example.m_bua.superapp.org.donboscoapp.MyAppWebViewClient());

// Url que carga la app (webview)
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/folderview?        id=0B009g1A1bhY7cDZlR2k0c0VYck0");
// Forzamos el webview para que abra los enlaces internos dentro de la la APP
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
// FIN AGREGADO

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            }

    // INI AGREGADO
@Override
// Detectar cuando se presiona el botón de retroceso
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

//Inserisco il menu' overflow
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return true;

}
//Inserisco la selezione dell'item sul menù overflow e lancio l'intent sull'item//
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.primo) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, com.example.m_bua.superapp.org.donboscoapp.MainActivityList.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);






}
```

}

My MainActivityList

```
public class MainActivityList extends Activity {

private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
private List<GroupEntity> mGroupCollection;
 /**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

/**
* Called when the activity is first created.
*/
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  prepareResource();
  initPage();
  // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
  // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
  client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

private void prepareResource() {

  mGroupCollection = new ArrayList<GroupEntity>();


     GroupEntity GA = new GroupEntity();{
     GA.Name = "Tornei Pulcini 2005" ;

     GroupEntity GB = new GroupEntity();
     GB.Name="Tornei Pulcini 2006 ";

     GroupEntity GC = new GroupEntity();
     GC.Name="Tornei Pulcini 2007 ";

     GroupEntity GD = new GroupEntity();
     GD.Name="Tornei Piccoli Amici 2008 ";

     GroupEntity GE = new GroupEntity();
     GE.Name="Tornei Piccoli Amici 2009 ";



        GroupItemEntity Primo2005 = GA.new GroupItemEntity();{
        Primo2005.Name = "Nessun Torneo In Evidenza";
        GA.GroupItemCollection.add(Primo2005);

        GroupItemEntity Primo2006 = GB.new GroupItemEntity();
        Primo2006.Name = "Nessun Torneo In Evidenza";
        GB.GroupItemCollection.add(Primo2006);

        GroupItemEntity Primo2007 = GC.new GroupItemEntity();
        Primo2007.Name = "Nessun Torneo In Evidenza";
        GC.GroupItemCollection.add(Primo2007);

        GroupItemEntity Primo2008 = GD.new GroupItemEntity();
        Primo2008.Name = "Torneo Pianazze";
        GD.GroupItemCollection.add(Primo2008);

        GroupItemEntity Primo2009 = GE.new GroupItemEntity();
        Primo2009.Name = "Nessun Torneo In Evidenza";
        GE.GroupItemCollection.add(Primo2009);

     }

     mGroupCollection.add(GA);
     mGroupCollection.add(GB);
     mGroupCollection.add(GC);
     mGroupCollection.add(GD);
     mGroupCollection.add(GE);
  }

 }


 private void initPage() {
 mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView)       findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
  ExpandableListAdapter adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,
        mExpandableListView, mGroupCollection);

  mExpandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

@Override
 public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();

  // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
  // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
  client.connect();
  Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
        Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
        "MainActivityList Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content    shown.
        // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app   activity's content,
        // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
        // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
        Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
        // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
        Uri.parse("android-  app://com.example.m_bua.superapp.org.donboscoapp/http/host/path")
  );
  AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
  }

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
   super.onStop();

   // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
   // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
   Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
   Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
        "MainActivityList Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content    shown.     // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app   activity's content,
        // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
        // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
        Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
        // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
        Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.m_bua.superapp.org.donboscoapp/http/host/path")
  );
  AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
  client.disconnect();
 }
}
```

My ExpandableListAdapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
private List<GroupEntity> mGroupCollection;
private int[] groupStatus;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context pContext,
                     ExpandableListView pExpandableListView,
                     List<GroupEntity> pGroupCollection) {
  mContext = pContext;
  mGroupCollection = pGroupCollection;
  mExpandableListView = pExpandableListView;
  groupStatus = new int[mGroupCollection.size()];

  setListEvent();
 }



 private void setListEvent() {

  mExpandableListView
        .setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

           @Override
           public void onGroupExpand(int arg0) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              groupStatus[arg0] = 1;
           }
        });

  mExpandableListView
        .setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

           @Override
           public void onGroupCollapse(int arg0) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              groupStatus[arg0] = 0;
           }
        });
  }

 @Override
 public String getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return mGroupCollection.get(arg0).GroupItemCollection.get(arg1).Name;
 }

 @Override
 public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public View getChildView(int arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2, View arg3,
     ViewGroup arg4) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  ChildHolder childHolder;
  if (arg3 == null) {
     arg3 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
           R.layout.list_group_item, null);

     childHolder = new ChildHolder();

     childHolder.title = (TextView) arg3.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
     arg3.setTag(childHolder);
  }else {
     childHolder = (ChildHolder) arg3.getTag();
  }
  childHolder.title.setText(mGroupCollection.get(arg0).GroupItemCollection.get(arg1).Name);
  return arg3;
 }

 @Override
 public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return mGroupCollection.get(arg0).GroupItemCollection.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return mGroupCollection.get(arg0);
  }

 @Override
 public int getGroupCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return mGroupCollection.size();
   }

 @Override
 public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return arg0;
   }

 @Override
 public View getGroupView(int arg0, boolean arg1, View arg2, ViewGroup arg3)          {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  GroupHolder groupHolder;
  if (arg2 == null) {
     arg2 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_group,
           null);
     groupHolder = new GroupHolder();
     groupHolder.img = (ImageView) arg2.findViewById(R.id.tag_img);
     groupHolder.title = (TextView) arg2.findViewById(R.id.group_title);
     arg2.setTag(groupHolder);
  } else {
     groupHolder = (GroupHolder) arg2.getTag();
  }
  if (groupStatus[arg0] == 0) {
     groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_down);
  } else {
     groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_up);
  }
  groupHolder.title.setText(mGroupCollection.get(arg0).Name);

  return arg2;
  }

 class GroupHolder {
  ImageView img;
  TextView title;
 }

class ChildHolder {
  TextView title;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return true;
}

}
```